# Build derived class in a function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base  {
public:
    Base() : _x(0), _y(0), _type(0){ ; }
    Base(int type) : _x(0), _y(0), _type(type){ ; }
    virtual ~Base() { ; }

    void setX(int x) { _x = x; }
    void setY(int y) { _y = y; }
    int type() { return _type; }

protected:
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _type;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived1() : Base(1) { ; }
    virtual ~Derived1() { ; }

    int getXY1() {
        return (_x * _y);
    }
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived2() : Base(2) { ; }
    virtual ~Derived2() { ; }

    int getXY2() {
        return (_x * _y);
    }
};

void buildDerived(Base* base, int type)
{
    if (type == 1)
        base = new Derived1();
    else if (type == 2)
        base = new Derived2();
}

int main(void)
{
    Base* base = 0;
    buildDerived(base, 1);  
    if (base && base->type() == 1){
        Derived1 *derived1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1 *>(base);
        if (derived1)
            cout << derived1->getXY1();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is build a derived class in a function passing a base class pointer as parameter.

I know that the above example could appear totally unuseful, but it's a simplified code taken from my application code.
In my code, in fact, I don't know from the earlier the type of derived: passing here the type as integer is a simplified way to show my case.

What I get is that the derived class function `getXY1` is never called since the `base` object is null.
What's happening here? How can I modify the source code above to achieve what I want, to build a derived class in a separate function starting from base class (since I don't know *a priori* what derived class will be built among the possible derived classes). After the call I could know the derived type and then make a downcasting.

Comment: `void buildDerived(Base* base, int type)`: you're not changing `base` ! either do ``void buildDerived(Base* &base, int type)`:` or return it.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your suggestion. Do you mean passing Base as reference? You typed both pointer and reference

Comment: see my answer. It's better with returning the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
void buildDerived(Base* base, int type)
{
    if (type == 1)
        base = new Derived1();
    else if (type == 2)
        base = new Derived2();
}
```

is modifying the *local* `base` parameter but not the variable in the `main` routine => `base` is still `NULL` in the main routine.

I would do this:

```
Base *buildDerived(int type)
{
    Base* base = nullptr;  // nullptr if you're using C++11
    if (type == 1)
        base = new Derived1();
    else if (type == 2)
        base = new Derived2();
    return base;
}
```

and in the `main`:

```
Base* base = buildDerived(1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result by passing (in some way) the Base class as parameter of the buildDerived function?

Comment: @ABCplus as Sam answer states, you can use `Base` copy constructor to partially initialize the object data, then fill the specific parameters with a specific constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take an existing `Base` object, and transform it into a derived object. C++ does not work this way.

What you can do is take an existing base object, and construct a new derived object, with its base object being copy-constructed.

You'll need to add another constructor to the derived class, let's use `Derived1` (and an analogous constructor for `Derived2`, in your case):

```
    Derived1(Base *p) : Base(*p) {}
```

This is going to construct the derived object's base by copying it from the existing base object. Of course, this only works when the base class has a default or an explicit copy constructor. With C++11, this can also be extended to use move constructors.

Comment: "You cannot take an existing Base object, and transform it into a derived object. C++ does not work this way." : isn't it how polimorphism works in C++?

Comment: No, polymorphism is something else. You already have an existing derived object, with polymorphism.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: wouldn't `Derived1(Base &p) : Base(p) {}` work? BTW your answer answers the _real_ OP question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That'll work too. A `const Base &` parameter would even be better. The OP referred to pointers, so that's what I went with.

Comment: `const` is the way!

Comment: How the `buildDerived` function should be changed according to your proposed solution?